# Get X value of max updatedAt with group in aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

DB Records

```
[
    _id: 1,
    user_id: 1,
    project_id: 1,
    updatedAt: 2020-12-20
]
[
    _id: 2,
    user_id: 1,
    project_id: 2,
    updatedAt: 2020-12-22
]
[
    _id: 3,
    user_id: 1,
    project_id: 3,
    updatedAt: 2020-12-21
]
[
    _id: 4,
    user_id: 2,
    project_id: 6,
    updatedAt: 2020-12-20
]
[
    _id: 5,
    user_id: 2,
    project_id: 5,
    updatedAt: 2020-12-23
]

userproject.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            "active":true
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_id",
            updatedAt : { $max : "$updatedAt" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort : { updatedAt: -1 }
    },
    { 
        $project: {
            "_id": "$_id",
        }
    }
])
```

Here is a code. i need the project_id of the or last updatedAt. i used the $first, $last but didn't get needed the result.
is any one have any idea what should i add to get the result.

Final result what's i need

```
[
    [
        _id: 1,
        project_id: 2
        updatedAt: 2020-12-22
    ],
    [
        _id: 2,
        project_id: 5
        updatedAt: 2020-12-23
    ]

]
```

The _id should give a user_id value and the project_id should give a last updatedAt project_id of that perticular user and at the end i need the updateAt as well

Comment: What result did you get? And what result would you expect to get?

Comment: @RobertSeaman i just add more information in post, Can you please look into it